# Android sdk Tools, Revision 12 does not update

Tags: android, emulation, revision

I'm fairly new to Android and today I fired it up and found a new update. I decided to install it, but it fails every time and display this message:

"Done. nothing was installed.

Downloading Android SDK Tools, revision 12
File not found: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\temp\tools_r12-windows.zip (Acces denied)"

I turned of my AV and any other program, turned off and on the SDK Manager but the error still appears. Can someone help me out? Can I update it without using the SDK Manager?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you updating through Eclipse? It sounds like a permissions issue to me - try right clicking and selecting run as administrator before updating.

Comment: He he he... It was not a problem with the Eclipse plugin, since I was using the SDK Manager. But you pointed me in the right direction. Executing it as an administrator let me installed it. Thanks, problem solved!! :D

Comment: @Versec Good to hear. I had a similar problem after shifting to 64-bit whenever I used something inside the 32-bit program files.